# Can someone explain the Blum cabinet profile scew position diagram?

Tags: drawers

Row A is if you have generic chipboard screws, row B is if you have fancy Blum system screws (part 661.145). What I don't understand is why the B row also shows generic chipboard screws. Do they really want you to use two kinds of screws?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "B" screws are not Blum-specific; Blum just happens to also make them.

Those are "euro screws" or "flat head euro screws".
The "problem" with euro screws is that they require pre-drilling, and chipboard screws usually don't.

I would assume that in the B-row, they want you to attach the rail with chipboard screws, so you can drill for euro screws without any fancy machinery or templates.

But in the end - nothing is set in stone. I've never used the screw positioning diagrams, and it is fine. Just keep in mind that (especially for the 65kg systems), the front of the rail will hold a lot of weight (hence the denser screw placement).

Comment: Given the tight tolerances on the slider positions I'm surprised they're encouraging not using at least slightly fancy templates, but your answer makes a lot of sense to me. Especially with the regular chipboard screws at either end.

Comment: @Spike Oh, I wouldn't agree with "not encouraging" to use templates (preferably theirs). If you look at their catalog, you will see a lot of different "accessories", from screws and screwdrivers to templates, assembly helpers and even machines (if you fancy a comprehensive solution). BUT they also give you the measurements, so as a non-professional (or even an aspiring professional), you wouldn't be forced to buy an expensive template, or buy a solution from a competitor that gives the measurements. In the end- piece of hardware sold is a piece of hardware sold.